# Sorting a complex Table w/nestled tables (but w/out tablesorter)

Tags: html, css, html-table

I ask you to indulge my ignorance up front: I really don't know what I'm talking about. But I've looked for all kinds of answers to the question I have and not found anything I could adopt/adapt for my situation.

I am trying to build a fairly complex HTML table that has a nested table inside on cell (recurringly). Basically the below. I'm working with the w3schools site, which has helped me get that far. I don't want to download anything to the website I will use this table on. (I don't even understand why I would have to or what I would do with a downloaded file.) I just figure that there has got to be a way to edit the script in such a way to ignore the nested cells. By distinguishing between parent and child cells perhaps?

The structure of the table may look weird, with the four 'invisible rows' up front, but it's the best way I could come up with to sort in essence one table cell by different parameters.

I am pretty sure I don't want to use table-sorter... I don't understand that at all... the "How TO - Sort a Table" on w3Schools makes so much more sense to me so far.

(I don't even know how to properly format coda as code here; I'm indenting the heck out of it but the pop-up still complains.)

Also: I want to have total control over the attributes/looks of the table.

I apologize for what's probably a mess below.  I saved the basic code here: https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FKLMTNSMVKET

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
            .CD_text
            {
                font-family:    arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
                font-size:      85%;
                text-align:  center;
            }
            .SORTING_text
            {
                font-family:    arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
                color:    whitesmoke;
                font-size:      1%;
                text-align:  center;
            }
            .ENSEMBLE_text
            {
                font-family:    Georgia, Times New Roman, serif;
                font-weight: normal;
                font-size:      110%;
                text-align:  left;
            }
            .DESCRIPTION_text
            {
                font-family:    Arial, Times New Roman, serif;
                font-weight: normal;
                font-size:      100%;
                text-align:  left;
            }

table, td, th {
    border: 1px dotted black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<h3>Beethoven Symphony Survey</h3>

<table id="myTable">
  <tr>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th onclick="sortTable(0)"><div class="DESCRIPTION_text">Name ⇕</div></th>
    <th onclick="sortTable(1)"><div class="DESCRIPTION_text">Orchestra ⇕</div></th>
    <th onclick="sortTable(2)"><div class="DESCRIPTION_text">Label ⇕</div></th>
    <th onclick="sortTable(3)"><div class="DESCRIPTION_text">Year Comp. ⇕</div></th>    
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><!--Abbado--></td>
    <td><!--Vienna Phil--></td>
    <td><!--DG--></td>
    <td><!--YEAR1--></td>

    <td colspan="4" data-sort-method='none'>
        <Table>
        <tr>    <td colspan="4">Claudio Abbado, Vienna Philharmonic
        <br>DG, 1990</td></tr>
        <tr>    
        <td>IMAGE<br>Text
        </td>
        <td>IMAGE<br>Text
        </td>
        <td>IMAGE<br>Text
        </td>
        <td>IMAGE<br>Text
        </td>
        </tr>
        </Table>
    </td>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><!--Abbado--></td>
    <td><!--Berlin Phil I--></td>
    <td><!--DG--></td>
    <td><!--YEAR2--></td>


    <td colspan="4" data-sort-method='none'>
        <Table>
        <tr>    <td colspan="4">Claudio Abbado, Vienna Philharmonic
        <br>DG, 1990</td></tr>
        <tr>    
        <td>IMAGE<br>Text
        </td>
        <td>IMAGE<br>Text
        </td>
        <td>IMAGE<br>Text
        </td>
        <td>IMAGE<br>Text
        </td>
        </tr>
        </Table>
      </td>
    </tr>
<tr>
    <td><!--Abbado--></td>
    <td><!--Berlin Phil II--></td>
    <td><!--DG--></td>
    <td><!--YEAR3--></td>

    <td colspan="4" data-sort-method='none'>
        <Table>
            <tr>    <td colspan="4">Claudio Abbado, Vienna Philharmonic
            <br>DG, 1990</td></tr>
            <tr>    
            <td>IMAGE<br>Text
            </td>
            <td>IMAGE<br>Text
            </td>
            <td>IMAGE<br>Text
            </td>
            <td>IMAGE<br>Text
            </td>
            </tr>
            </Table>
        </td>
    </tr>
<tr>
    <td><!--Albrecht--></td>
    <td><!--Yomiuri Nippon--></td>
    <td><!--Exton--></td>
    <td><!--YEAR4--></td>

    <td colspan="4" data-sort-method='none'>
        <Table>
            <tr>    <td colspan="4">Gerhard Albrecht, Yomiuri Nippon
        <br>Exton, 1993</td></tr>
            <tr>    
            <td>IMAGE<br>Text
            </td>
            <td>IMAGE<br>Text
            </td>
            <td>IMAGE<br>Text
            </td>
            <td>IMAGE<br>Text
            </td>
            </tr>
            </Table>
        </td>
    </tr>
<tr>
    <td><!--Karajan--></td>
    <td><!--Philharmonia--></td>
    <td><!--Exton--></td>
    <td><!--YEAR5--></td>

    <td colspan="4" data-sort-method='none'>
        <Table>
            <tr>    <td colspan="4">Herbert von Karajan, Berlin Philharmonic
        <br>DG, 1975</td></tr>
            <tr>    
                <td>IMAGE<br>Text</td>

                <td>IMAGE<br>Text</td>

                <td>IMAGE<br>Text</td>

                <td>IMAGE<br>Text</td>
            </tr>
        </Table>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>



</body>
</html>

    <script>
function sortTable(n) {
  var table, rows, switching, i, x, y, shouldSwitch, dir, switchcount = 0;
  table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  switching = true;
  //Set the sorting direction to ascending:
  dir = "asc"; 
  /*Make a loop that will continue until
  no switching has been done:*/
  while (switching) {
    //start by saying: no switching is done:
    switching = false;
    rows = table.getElementsByTagName("TR");
    /*Loop through all table rows (except the
    first, which contains table headers):*/
    for (i = 1; i < (rows.length - 1); i++) {
      //start by saying there should be no switching:
      shouldSwitch = false;
      /*Get the two elements you want to compare,
      one from current row and one from the next:*/
      x = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("TD")[n];
      y = rows[i + 1].getElementsByTagName("TD")[n];
      /*check if the two rows should switch place,
      based on the direction, asc or desc:*/
      if (dir == "asc") {
        if (x.innerHTML.toLowerCase() > y.innerHTML.toLowerCase()) {
          //if so, mark as a switch and break the loop:
          shouldSwitch= true;
          break;
        }
      } else if (dir == "desc") {
        if (x.innerHTML.toLowerCase() < y.innerHTML.toLowerCase()) {
          //if so, mark as a switch and break the loop:
          shouldSwitch= true;
          break;
        }
      }
    }
    if (shouldSwitch) {
      /*If a switch has been marked, make the switch
      and mark that a switch has been done:*/
      rows[i].parentNode.insertBefore(rows[i + 1], rows[i]);
      switching = true;
      //Each time a switch is done, increase this count by 1:
      switchcount ++;      
    } else {
      /*If no switching has been done AND the direction is "asc",
      set the direction to "desc" and run the while loop again.*/
      if (switchcount == 0 && dir == "asc") {
        dir = "desc";
        switching = true;
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to get help in how to use table-sorter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to use that JS code, the easiest solution is to just get rid of the child tables and replace the image blocks with DIVs, like this:

```js
function sortTable(n) {
  var table, rows, switching, i, x, y, shouldSwitch, dir, switchcount = 0;
  table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  switching = true;
  //Set the sorting direction to ascending:
  dir = "asc";
  /*Make a loop that will continue until
  no switching has been done:*/
  while (switching) {
    //start by saying: no switching is done:
    switching = false;
    rows = table.getElementsByTagName("TR");
    /*Loop through all table rows (except the
    first, which contains table headers):*/
    for (i = 1; i < (rows.length - 1); i++) {
      //start by saying there should be no switching:
      shouldSwitch = false;
      /*Get the two elements you want to compare,
      one from current row and one from the next:*/
      x = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("TD")[n];
      y = rows[i + 1].getElementsByTagName("TD")[n];
      /*check if the two rows should switch place,
      based on the direction, asc or desc:*/
      if (dir == "asc") {
        if (x.innerHTML.toLowerCase() > y.innerHTML.toLowerCase()) {
          //if so, mark as a switch and break the loop:
          shouldSwitch = true;
          break;
        }
      } else if (dir == "desc") {
        if (x.innerHTML.toLowerCase() < y.innerHTML.toLowerCase()) {
          //if so, mark as a switch and break the loop:
          shouldSwitch = true;
          break;
        }
      }
    }
    if (shouldSwitch) {
      /*If a switch has been marked, make the switch
      and mark that a switch has been done:*/
      rows[i].parentNode.insertBefore(rows[i + 1], rows[i]);
      switching = true;
      //Each time a switch is done, increase this count by 1:
      switchcount++;
    } else {
      /*If no switching has been done AND the direction is "asc",
      set the direction to "desc" and run the while loop again.*/
      if (switchcount == 0 && dir == "asc") {
        dir = "desc";
        switching = true;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.CD_text {
  font-family: arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 85%;
  text-align: center;
}

.SORTING_text {
  font-family: arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: whitesmoke;
  font-size: 1%;
  text-align: center;
}

.ENSEMBLE_text {
  font-family: Georgia, Times New Roman, serif;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 110%;
  text-align: left;
}

.DESCRIPTION_text {
  font-family: Arial, Times New Roman, serif;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 100%;
  text-align: left;
}

table,
td,
th {
  border: 1px dotted black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<h3>Beethoven Symphony Survey</h3>
<table id="myTable">
  <tr>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th onclick="sortTable(0)"><div class="DESCRIPTION_text">Name ⇕</div></th>
    <th onclick="sortTable(1)"><div class="DESCRIPTION_text">Orchestra ⇕</div></th>
    <th onclick="sortTable(2)"><div class="DESCRIPTION_text">Label ⇕</div></th>
    <th onclick="sortTable(3)"><div class="DESCRIPTION_text">Year Comp. ⇕</div></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><!--Abbado--></td>
    <td><!--Vienna Phil--></td>
    <td><!--DG--></td>
    <td><!--YEAR1--></td>
    <td colspan="4" data-sort-method='none'> Claudio Abbado, Vienna Philharmonic <br>
      DG, 1990 <br>
      <div style="display:inline-block;border:1px solid #F00;">IMAGE<br>
        Text</div>
      <div style="display:inline-block;border:1px solid #F00;">IMAGE<br>
        Text</div>
      <div style="display:inline-block;border:1px solid #F00;">IMAGE<br>
        Text</div>
      <div style="display:inline-block;border:1px solid #F00;">IMAGE<br>
        Text</div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><!--Abbado--></td>
    <td><!--Berlin Phil I--></td>
    <td><!--DG--></td>
    <td><!--YEAR2--></td>
    <td colspan="4" data-sort-method='none'> Claudio Abbado, Vienna Philharmonic <br>
      DG, 1990 <br>
      <div style="display:inline-block;border:1px solid #F00;">IMAGE<br>
        Text</div>
      <div style="display:inline-block;border:1px solid #F00;">IMAGE<br>
        Text</div>
      <div style="display:inline-block;border:1px solid #F00;">IMAGE<br>
        Text</div>
      <div style="display:inline-block;border:1px solid #F00;">IMAGE<br>
        Text</div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><!--Abbado--></td>
    <td><!--Berlin Phil II--></td>
    <td><!--DG--></td>
    <td><!--YEAR3--></td>
    <td colspan="4" data-sort-method='none'> Claudio Abbado, Vienna Philharmonic <br>
      DG, 1990 <br>
      <div style="display:inline-block;border:1px solid #F00;">IMAGE<br>
        Text</div>
      <div style="display:inline-block;border:1px solid #F00;">IMAGE<br>
        Text</div>
      <div style="display:inline-block;border:1px solid #F00;">IMAGE<br>
        Text</div>
      <div style="display:inline-block;border:1px solid #F00;">IMAGE<br>
        Text</div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><!--Albrecht--></td>
    <td><!--Yomiuri Nippon--></td>
    <td><!--Exton--></td>
    <td><!--YEAR4--></td>
    <td colspan="4" data-sort-method='none'> Gerhard Albrecht, Yomiuri Nippon <br>
      Exton, 1993 <br>
      <div style="display:inline-block;border:1px solid #F00;">IMAGE<br>
        Text</div>
      <div style="display:inline-block;border:1px solid #F00;">IMAGE<br>
        Text</div>
      <div style="display:inline-block;border:1px solid #F00;">IMAGE<br>
        Text</div>
      <div style="display:inline-block;border:1px solid #F00;">IMAGE<br>
        Text</div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><!--Karajan--></td>
    <td><!--Philharmonia--></td>
    <td><!--Exton--></td>
    <td><!--YEAR5--></td>
    <td colspan="4" data-sort-method='none'> Herbert von Karajan, Berlin Philharmonic <br>
      DG, 1975 <br>
      <div style="display:inline-block;border:1px solid #F00;">IMAGE<br>
        Text</div>
      <div style="display:inline-block;border:1px solid #F00;">IMAGE<br>
        Text</div>
      <div style="display:inline-block;border:1px solid #F00;">IMAGE<br>
        Text</div>
      <div style="display:inline-block;border:1px solid #F00;">IMAGE<br>
        Text</div></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Please forgive the inline CSS in my example. You'll want to move that to a stylesheet. You'll also want to correct your data-entry wonkiness with the hidden columns.

But that should make it work, more or less.